# Is it possible to disable requestAnimationFrame in D3 v4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I understand that according to the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer) D3 will use

> requestAnimationFrame for fluid animation (if available), switching to setTimeout for delays longer than 24ms.

I would like to disable `requestAnimationFrame` and only use `setTimeout` as I would like animations to look more regular without the random rate change which I think is caused by `requestAnimationFrame`. I do not want to use `setInterval`.

The animations are performed in the typical fashion within a `setTimeout` callback:

```
 function render(){

    // perform d3 rendering here

    setTimeout(render, 1000);
 }
 setTimeout(render, 1000);
```

Comment: There is the nuclear option `delete window.requestAnimationFrame` (and similar for vendor-prefixed variations) though D3 might support a better opt-out

Comment: Can't you just set your delay to 25 ms enforcing the use of `setTimeout`? Given the intervals of 1000 ms in your code this initial delay won't carry much weight.

Comment: Thanks but requestAnimationFrame was still being called from D3. I tried disabling it within the d3 source. It worked, but it did not improve the stuttering of the animation so I guess requestAnimationFrame is not the issue causing the inconsistent timing of the animations.